# Ubuntu root .bashrc file

Tags: 12.04, root, ruby, bashrc, rvm

I was installing [rvm](http://tokarchuk.ru/2011/05/installing-rvm-ruby-1-9-rails-3-0-1-in-ubuntu/)

and for some reasons i changed first line on root's `.bashrc`
what was there?

i inserter `if [[ -n "$PS1" ]];` then and see that i'm root, can't undo... What string is first like if... in Ubuntu 12.04 for root?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not awfully clear on what you've done & why, but I believe this is what you're asking for (NB: taken from 12.10 - it should be similar):

```
ace@ace2:~/src$ sudo head -n 20 /root/.bashrc
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[ -z "$PS1" ] && return

# don't put duplicate lines in the history. See bash(1) for more options
# ... or force ignoredups and ignorespace
HISTCONTROL=ignoredups:ignorespace

# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend

# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000

# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
```